# How to start Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I want to implement Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm, and I'm using a multi-level dictionary to represent my graph. For example:

```
g = {'A': {'C': 2}, 'B': {'B': 4, 'A': 2}}
```

I know how to access the inner dictionary using double `for` loops. But if the user inputs a starting point and an ending point, I face a problem searching for my starting point inside the dictionary using this `for` loop:

```
start = input("Starting point : ")
for start in g:
    print start
```

This will instead print the the keys inside and it will always start from the first key and go through the graph. That's the opposite of what the algorithm says, which is to compare the source point with all the other nodes, and then the point after based on the weight with all the other nodes, and so on.

Can you suggest a way to go about this? How can I start from node B instead of A for example instead of starting from the first key?

Also, do you recommend this dictionary method or is there a better way to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm solves the single-source shortest-path problem. Given a graph and a vertex in the graph, it finds the shortest path to every other vertex.

If you want your implementation to run fast, you must use a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). It's fine to use a dictionary to represent the graph initially, but you'll want to extract the edges and insert them into the priority queue. Recall that in each iteration of Dijkstra's algorithm, you must pick the cheapest edge among all the edges that cross the frontier between the unexplored part of the graph and the part you've already explored. With a min-cost priority queue, you can pop the cheapest edge off the queue in each iteration.

A simple and efficient implementation of a priority queue is a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). I recommend that you either use Python's built-in [heap queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) or implement your own min-heap with a list.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help and edit. You said that it is fine to implement dictionaries at first but then I need to extract the edges and the insert them into the queue, is that by taking the whole graph and write it as a heap?!

Comment: There are several ways to do it. I would say that the easiest way is to start with a heap that contains all edges incident on the start vertex, which is the first explored vertex. Remove the cheapest edge `(u, v)` where `u` is an explored vertex and `v` is unexplored. Add the vertex `v` to the explored vertices, and add to the heap all edges from `v` to unexplored vertices. That's one iteration. In total you run `n-1` iterations where `n` is the number of vertices in the graph.

Comment: I really apprieciate your help sir but I feel lost, maybe it is due to my lack of firm knowledge on python, but I really want to learn! Could you please guide me to what I need to know so I can finally figure it out?

Comment: I strongly recommend Tim Roughgarden's [first algorithm course](https://class.coursera.org/algo/lecture). If you can access the video lectures, go to week 5 and watch the lectures on Dijkstra's algorithm. That should give you a good foundation for implementing it.

Comment: I watched the videos a few times now especially the first two. I understand what's going on exactly, but I don't know why everytime I try I am still losing it midway, maybe mainly due to how represent `A[s] + **Lsv** `. How do I extract `Lsv`, which is a represintation of the connection, from the nested dictionary? I tried using `for`loops but I am still not getting it.

Comment: And another one that I have been struggling with since I started, let's imagine I have A->B->C, how does A know that it can go to C through B?

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo I thinks it is easier to start with a heap with only the start node. No need to pre-insert the edges incident to the start node.

Answer (score 3):

The starting node should be a parameter of your dijkstra function. The function signature should be something like `def dijkstra(graph, start):`.

To iterate over the connected nodes, I'd use:

```
for node, cost in graph[start].items():
    print node, cost
```

Also in dijkstra you should have a data structure to hold the nodes not yet explored decreasingly ordered by cost. Usually a priority queue is used.

**Here's a tip:** The main loop inside the dijkstra function won't be a for loop, but a while loop checking there's still nodes to explore.

Comment: OH! Does that mean that there will always be one starting point instead of just finding the shortest path between any two nodes?!

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of a different implementation of dijksta, can you provide some pseudocode of what you're trying to build.

Comment: Dijkstra is a single-source shortest path algorithm, you'll get the distance to every other node in the graph from the starting node. If you want all-pairs you should use Floyd-Warshall.

Comment: btw if I may ask sir, why did you suggest to use while loop instead of for loop? I found a code that has only one for in it for the dijkstra algorithm so I am wondering..

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad The code I have in mind is the one described by Michael Laszlo in the comments.

Comment: could you please explain to me how to start with a heap with only the start node? Because I think we need a loop to extract the edges incident to the vertix and then extract the cheapest, but I am not sure how to implement your method sir...

Comment: Build a heap object, insert only the start node. Use a while loop with the condition being that the heap is not empty, pop the cheapest node off the heap and insert every incident node that has not been visited before. The loop will end when the heap is emtpy and hence all nodes have been visited.

Comment: I just tried to do this but heaps in python deal with lists and not dictionaries while my graph is represented using dictionaries, how do I go around this?!
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heap.py", line 12, in <module>
    smalles= heapq.heappop(heap)
TypeError: heap argument must be a list`

This is my expermintation code so far:
`g= {'S': {"V": 1, 'W': 4},
 'V': {'T':6, 'W':2},
 'W': {'T':3,},
 'T':{}}

heap = g['S']
smalles= heapq.heappop(heap)`

Comment: You just need to store the node and the cost so far. So your heap can start like this [(0, 'S')], then you'll pop the start node off the heap and push it's adjacent nodes and end up with something like this [(1, 'V'), (4, 'W')] and so on. Every time you pop a node off the heap you'll get the cheapest route to that node from the start node. Avoid revisiting nodes already visited.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
for start in g:
    print start
```

has the variable `start` iterate over every key of your dictionary. If you wanted to print the value/subdictionary that corresponds to your starting point in the dictionary, just use

```
print g[start]
```

As for the algorithn itself, Diego Allen's advice is right.

Comment: yep, that's the problem actually. But then what if I want to go through all the nodes to search for the nodes that are connected together and finally find the path? I need to use a loop, right?

Comment: Yeap, you'll probably need a loop. But instead of iterating over every key and picking the one with the minimum cost in each step, you should use a structure like a priority queue, as Dallen suggests. This will save you precious time in each iteration.